# how to call struts-jsp application from a core java application programatically at run time?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

i have a core java application and a struts2 (jsp) application which use tomcat server running on local host. i need to call or restart my struts application from my core java application if it meets certain conditions. Seeks your good suggestion or snippets to do so.

Comment: not sure what you mean by restart struts2 application, i believe you want to restart your server.Please be more clear as what you want.

Comment: @umesh, thanks for your reply. actually both of my java application and struts-jsp applications are running.

Comment: my question is still unanswered, do you want to restart your server from your web-app running on same server or you want to restart it from a standalone java program

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi THANKS for ur reply. Actually both my java application & struts-jsp(using local host Tomcat Server) application are running on a same PC at a time. My java application always listening to a port and receives a file(zipped file) and unzip it. My struts-jsp application is displaying the content from the unzipped file on the browser. So here i have a condition on my java application, that whenever it receives a new zip file, it will unzip it and have to restart the struts-jsp application, so that it can display the new file content. So, how can restart my struts-jsp application ?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi , thanks, which way better, as i have the condition at standalone java pgm ?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190300/how-to-start-and-stop-an-tomcat-container-with-java?rq=1. Also not sure why you need to restart your application to show content on browser